# How to set flags with Renderer2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In the setStyle method for Renderer2, you can set flags which is of type RendererStyleFlags2, which is an enum. I've not worked with enums much and can't figure out how to actually set this as the fourth argument passed to setStyle. 
Here is the template for the method:

`abstract setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags?: RendererStyleFlags2): void`

I've seen lots of examples of setStyle, but none that actually pass this flags argument. I'd like to be able to set this to important, but don't know how to successfully implement this.

Can anyone assist please.

Comment: This function has a bug. Look this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12009. So even if you want to give 'important' it will not work.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the heads up.